# Spring Boot instinitate @Bean according to Condition

Tags: spring, spring-boot

im working in spring boot project where i want to instantiate a Restemplate Bean with Interceptors , my issue that i don't want to duplicate the code because there is just the header that changes for each conciguration. this is my code :

```
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("restTemplateOne")
  public RestTemplate restTemplateWithAccessToken() {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
      .interceptors((HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) -> {

        //this is the only header that i want to add for 
        request.getHeaders().set("MY_PARTICULAR_HEADER", "my value");

       request.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"my auth value"); 

        return execution.execute(request, body);

      }).build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("restTemplateTwo")
  public RestTemplate restTemplateWithIdToken() {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
      .interceptors((HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) -> {

        request.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"my auth value");

        return execution.execute(request, body);

      }).build();
  }
  
  
  
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("restTemplateOne")
  private RestTemplate restTemplateOne;
  
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("restTemplateTwo")
  private RestTemplate restTemplateTwo;
```

do you have any idea how i can optimize code to avoid duplication . something like adding a parameter to the method and adding the header or not according to the condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at `@FeignClient` implementation instead of `RestTemplate`. There are many advantages on this point.

Comment: thanks @SerhiiZhura we already use Feign but it's not mature . we have problems with Soap WS and XML mapping , plus call WS with MultipartFile so this is why we use Restemplatebecause we have the full control of our WS calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract and parameterize your interceptor:

```java
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateOne")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateWithAccessToken() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .interceptors(new CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor(true))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateTwo")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateWithIdToken() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .interceptors(new CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor(false))
                .build();
    }

    private static class CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
        private boolean needParticularHeader;

        public CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor(boolean needParticularHeader) {
            this.needParticularHeader = needParticularHeader;
        }

        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request,
                                            byte[] body,
                                            ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            if (needParticularHeader) {
                //this is the only header that i want to add for
                request.getHeaders().set("MY_PARTICULAR_HEADER", "my value");
            }

            request.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "my auth value");

            return execution.execute(request, body);

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @dekkard . i like your suggestion but i can't extract the interceptor this way since i have other  Feign Calls so i think this CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor will intercept my feign calls and add the headers. you confirm ?

Comment: `CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor` will only intercept requests that are performed by a `RestTemplate` that was explicitly configured to use this interceptor. Feign doesn't use `RestTemplate` at all - it uses OkHttpClient or ApacheHttpClient directly instead. Anyway you can easily check if your interceptor is invoked or not - just add some logs to the interceptor and call your Feign client.

Comment: thanks it works fine. i accepted your answer (y)